# There are no nonzero cocycles on $U$ vanishing on a def. retract of $U$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Playing around with cochains, I think I showed the following:

**Proposition:** Suppose $U$ deformation retracts onto its subspace $A$, and suppose $\varphi \in C^k(U)$ is a singular cocycle which vanishes on $A$. Then $\varphi$ is identically zero.

**Proof:** Induction on $k$. If $k=0$, then note that any point in $U$ can be connected to a point in $A$ by a path (the image of the point in $U$ under the deformation retraction), whence the cocycle condition implies that $\varphi \equiv 0$. Now suppose it holds true for $k=n-1$, and let $\varphi \in C^{n}(U)$ be a cocycle vanishing on $A$. Then it is certainly a $(U,A)$ coboundary (since $H^\bullet (U,A)$ is trivial), so it factors as $\varphi = \mu \circ \partial$, where $\mu \in C^{k-1}(U)$ vanishes on $A$. By the inductive hypothesis, $\mu \equiv 0$, and so $\varphi \equiv 0$. $\blacksquare$

I was surprised I had to use induction. Does anyone see an easier way to show this? Is it obvious in a way I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

As my friend Kevin wisely points out to me, the above proof breaks down because we cannot assume $\mu$ is a cocycle.

Comment: Indeed, the proposition is not true. Consider $A = \{z \in \Bbb C : |z| \leq 1\} \subset \Bbb C$ and $U = \{z \in \Bbb C : |z| < 2\}\subset \Bbb C$. Triangulate $A$ by joining a few boundary points to the origin. Then extend this triangulation to all of $U$ carefully. $\varphi$ be the 1-cocycle on $U$ which takes $0$ on all the edges inside $A$ and $\pm 1$'s on the edges outside $A$ (done in an appropriate way so that the cocycle condition is satisfied). This is clearly $0$ on $A$ yet nonzero globally. What is true is that it must merely be homologous to an identically $0$ cocycle.